# Multiple times adding same line into yaml file (ansible playbook)

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

I want to add one line multiple times in a specific between lines. I tried with my playbook but just once added to the last one and it should add same line with From Earth.

**My playbook**

```
- name: Update the file
  lineinfile:
    dest: /sample/config.file
    insertafter: ' Earth .* '
    line: '    This is template'
```

**My initial file**

```
Hello World
   [From Earth]
Hello World
   [From Earth]
Hello World
   [From Earth]
Hello World
   [From Earth]
```

**My Desire Output**

```
Hello World
   [From Earth]
   This is template
Hello World
   [From Earth]
   This is template
Hello World
   [From Earth]
   This is template
Hello World
   [From Earth]
   This is template
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `replace`:

```
 - name: Replace
   replace:
       path: file.txt
       regexp: 'Earth]\n(?!{{repl_str}})'
       replace: 'Earth]\n{{repl_str}}'
   vars:
     repl_str: '   This is template\n'
```

Comment: I tried your solution kind of works but I missed something and updated my question and added special character [ ]. How can I use like this?

Comment: Why do you need the special character?  Example?

Comment: I updated in my main question file and output parts. [From Earth]

Comment: Ah, I had to refresh.  Updated answer to add character.

Comment: This will NOT be idempotent.

Comment: Edited to be idempotent.

Comment: Im getting syntax error(ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to have been in '/sample/config.file': line 5, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

      replace: 'Earth]\n{{repl_str}}'
    vars:
    ^ here)

Comment: Okey edited your syntax, now working thank you for the answer.

Comment: One more question, I changed `repl_str: '   {{ template }}\n'` the line like this.Now Im taking **template** variable from different yml file.First run successfully add line but when try second or more times.Doesn't effect the file, didn't add anything after one time.Every trigger I need to add different variable into the file.

Comment: That is correct behavior.  Ansible tasks should be written to be idempotent, meaning that a change is made once and only once.